# Mesh deforms after automatic weights (IK and pole vector)

Tags: rigging, bones

Blend : https://gofile.io/?c=4od4mq[image]

My self made rig completely deforms after automatic weights. I've altered the rotation of the IK bone, in pose mode and reset the rotation of the bones with alt+G. When I created the bones, I did not pay attention to rotation axes. Did I mention I did not took the time to rename the bones?

What I might think is the problem is the legs, of the original mesh were not completely in T Pose. 
Furthermore, the lower part of the mesh breaks after the process, which is caused by other problems.
I Followed this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM8mOq9RiNE

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that’s the main problem is that you need to correct the *Pole Angle* of your IK bones or they are going to rotate crazy once in *Pose* mode, -90° for both right and left IK.

Also in *Edit* mode you need to bend the knees bones a bit forwards so that they’ll bend correctly in *Pose* mode. And join the 2 pole targets to your main armature. Make sure some bones (controllers, pole targets, root) won’t deform the mesh: Select each of them and disable their *Deform* option. And it looks like you have a lot of overlapping vertices, so <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* and play with the parameters.

[image]