# Weight Paint subtract doesn't work as I expect

Tags: rigging

[image]
[image]

[image]

Hii Guys can anyone help with this? i am having some trouble with automatic weights. when i substract the weight under the right leg.its just not getting a smooth substract. it just shrink itself when i substract the weights. please can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: (1) Check **Preserve Volume** in the armature modifier. (2) Make sure your bone isn't rotated in pose mode. It looks rotated  by 180° due to the IK constraint on the next bone. (The IK modifier has an adjustable angle.)

Comment: i done what you said. i used the preserve volume.it still not solved . but one of my left leg ik is 180 and my right led ik pole angle is 0. even i changed both two iks to zero. Still it stucks. Can you give me your Mail. So i can send my File to you. And later you can say me the mistake what i have done please....Rather than Legs .My all weights are working Well when i substract/Add.

Comment: Thank You so Much Leander Sir, My Problem is solved now .What you said is true there was a problem with the ik angle .the bone is rotated in the pose mode. Thanks for knowing my Mistake. Now i have adjusted my pole angle till it get perfect. Thanks a Lot Sir.....

Comment: That sounds great, I have found another question with the same problem and will link it for future users.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Mesh deforms after automatic weights (IK and pole vector)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149995/mesh-deforms-after-automatic-weights-ik-and-pole-vector)

Comment: Thanks for Helping Me Sir. My problem Solved..